# What fonts come with Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been having a problem with a python package that I maintain: the fonts displayed by my package appear differently when run on my recent WSL Ubuntu installation, compared with how they appear on three other Ubuntu installations that I use.

I eventually tracked the problem down to the fact that in the installations that work ok, there are dozens of different fonts in the `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` directory, but in my WSL ubuntu I see only dejavu.

```
dino@DINO:/usr/share/fonts/truetype$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Aug 21 13:52 dejavu
```

I am trying to figure which fonts ***should*** be in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/` **immediately after installing** any given Ubuntu distro (or any disto of linux for that matter), but I can't seem to find this information.

---

**Where I can find out what fonts *should* come with any specific Ubuntu distribution?**  Thanks.

---

Comment: Can you please share the screenshots of different font appearances?

Comment: The different font appearances are irrelevant.  ([If you are really interested you can see them here](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/insight-into-pytest-mpl-font-differences/21477)).  I have already debugged that problem and determined that the application is looking for `LiberationSans`.  On 2 of my 3 Ubuntu distros it finds it (here: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf`) **but on my `WSL Ubuntu`** the application falls back to the only font it can find, which is `DejaVuSans`.  Trying to understand why WSL Ubuntu has only the one truetype font.

Comment: Your problem may have to do with the fact that WSL is not intended for graphical applications, much less a desktop environment. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Comment: @Nmath  It is true that WSL by itself does not support linux graphical applications, but this is not an issue.  You simply install a windows-based Xserver such as VcXSrv, and then configure (via .bashrc) your WSL linux to use the windows-based xserver.  It works like a charm.   It is clear that WSL Ubuntu now does not include the fonts listed in the answer below.  I fixed my problem by manually installing them.  At this point I would just like to get verification that WSL Ubuntu **used to** ship with fonts.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu server has ever shipped with a bunch of fonts. Why would it? Nobody's saying you can't tinker and play all you want with WSL, or that you can't get a desktop or GUI software to run.  But at the end of the day, you have a very large toolbox in terms of ways to run Linux/Ubuntu software. Usually it's best to choose an *appropriate* tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS and this is in my fonts folder:

```
abyssinica
dejavu
droid
fonts-beng-extra
fonts-deva-extra
fonts-gujr-extra
fonts-guru-extra
fonts-kalapi
fonts-orya-extra
fonts-telu-extra
fonts-yrsa-rasa
freefont
Gargi
Gubbi
hack
kacst
kacst-one
lao
liberation
liberation2
lohit-assamese
lohit-bengali
lohit-devanagari
lohit-gujarati
lohit-kannada
lohit-malayalam
lohit-oriya
lohit-punjabi
lohit-tamil
lohit-tamil-classical
lohit-telugu
malayalam
Nakula
Navilu
noto
openoffice
padauk
pagul
Sahadeva
samyak
samyak-fonts
Sarai
sinhala
tibetan-machine
tlwg
ttf-khmeros-core
ubuntu
```

I can't tell you for other distros but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks pretty much identical with my `VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"` distro, which is working fine.  I had an earlier` WSL Ubuntu 18` that was working fine also.  But I had to reinstall Windows, and now every `WSL Ubuntu` that I install seems to have only `dejavu`.  I wonder if microsoft changed it and stopped distributing fonts with their WSL Ubuntu distros.  How to find out?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything about that in the release notes: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes . But perhaps the difference is between `WSL` and `WSL 2`.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be WSL vs WSL2 related.  The problem first appeared when I upgraded to WSL2 and deleted and reinstalled Ubuntu.  But I have since clean reinstalled windows and went back to plain WSL and still have the problem.  I now know the problem is missing fonts.  Just trying to figure out if I can track down why.